# howto: Nesting extension method calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my cshtml I have the following line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "field size4",
placeholder = LogOnUIMessages.EmailFieldLabel, id = "LoginEmailAddress",
name="LoginEmail", autofocus = "", required=""})
```

Because the field 'required' is already defined as a data annotation (The attribute is added for easy & clean JS validation), I wanted to write a new implementation of TextBoxFor that includes the 'required' based on the data annotation:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LogOnUIMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = LogOnResourceKeys.ErrorEmailIsRequired)]
[StringLength(UserNameMaxLength, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LogOnUIMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = LogOnResourceKeys.ErrorUserNameMaxLenghtExceeded)]
[RegularExpression(RegEx.CorrectEmailRegExp, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ProfileUIMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = LogOnResourceKeys.ErrorEmailIsNotValid)]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public String EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

(there are more annotation given, just showing the most important one now) As a proof of concept, I wrote both an extension method and a helper method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
{
    return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
}
```

and

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomTextBoxForToo<TModel, TProperty>(
        HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
{
    return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, 
    HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}
```

But when called like:

```
@Html.CustomTextBoxFor(
    m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "field size4", placeholder = 
    LogOnUIMessages.EmailFieldLabel, id = "LoginEmailAddress",
    name="LoginEmail", autofocus = "", required=""})
```

And

```
@PocExtensions.CustomTextBoxForToo(
    this.Html, m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "field size4", 
    placeholder = LogOnUIMessages.EmailFieldLabel, 
    id = "LoginEmailAddress", name="LoginEmail", 
    autofocus = "", required=""})
```

They both return:

```
<input autofocus="" class="field size4" id="LoginEmailAddress" 
name="EmailAddress" placeholder="vul je e-mail adres in" 
required="" type="text" value="">
```

Instead of what I expected:

```
<input autofocus="" class="field size4" data-val="true" 
data-val-length="Het opgegeven emailadres is te lang." 
data-val-length-max="128" data-val-regex="Het opgegeven adres is niet geldig" 
data-val-regex-pattern="[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-
9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])
?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?" 
data-val-required="Dit veld is verplicht." id="LoginEmailAddress" 
name="EmailAddress" placeholder="vul je e-mail adres in" 
required="" type="text" value="">
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit #1, additional information**

```
IEnumerable<ModelValidator> modelValidators=metadata.GetValidators(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
```

returns 4 validators. While:

```
htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(elementName, metadata);
```

returns an empty collection?

**Edit #2**
I've found the cause of my problem, but not yet a clean solution. The problem is the GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes function which is called within the GetTextBoxFor function.
This doesn't reach the data annotation on my object, because the name used when calling the function, should have a [CLASS].[PROPERTY] structure while the ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText function (used within GetTextBoxFor) only yields the [PROPERTY] name.

Now I wonder, is this a bug or is this by design?

I've managed to put together a POC:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    object htmlAttributes
)
{
    var elementName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

    var dataAnnotationAttributeDictionary = htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes
(
    String.Format("{0}.{1}", metadata.ContainerType.FullName, elementName),
    metadata
);
var providedAttributeDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, providedAttributeDictionary.Concat(dataAnnotationAttributeDictionary).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value));
    }
```

**Now my question is: (how) can this be done better?**

Comment: Using regular expressions? ;)

Comment: I don't see any code that reads the attributes, so how do you think this should work?

Comment: @Daniel: I call the function (TextBoxFor) that does the attribute insertion, from within my own extension (CustomTextBoxFor). Which is, for as far as I know, the same as if it was called directly from the cshtml. So I expect the original method (TextBoxFor) would insert all the attributes, based on the annotations. My code was just a plain test for wrapping an extension method.

Comment: The string you expect - where do you get it from? Is it returned, when you use `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead of `@Html.CustomTextBoxFor`?

Comment: I am asking, because the expected output doesn't match the property you showed...

Comment: What I expect is from when I call @Html.TextBoxFor. The full collection of annotations on the property is:
'[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(LogOnUIMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName=LogOnResourceKeys.ErrorEmailIsRequired)]
[StringLength(UserNameMaxLength, ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(LogOnUIMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName=LogOnResourceKeys.ErrorUserNameMaxLenghtExceeded)]
[RegularExpression(RegEx.CorrectEmailRegExp, ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(ProfileUIMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName=LogOnResourceKeys.ErrorEmailIsNotValid)]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]'

Comment: @Daniel, sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 0):

In my helper classes, when I am adding data and then passing to the underlying MVC 3 helpers, I use the following:

```
return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, expression, htmlAttributes);
```

I have not checked into the MVC 3 source code for this issue, but I expect that calling through `htmlHelper` is the cause of your issue.

Comment: Also tried: `return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, (IDictionary<string, object>) HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));` Didn't make any difference.